# child and footer of GridTile giving ' 'size.isFinite': is not true' error

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, gridview, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a widget tree consisting of a grid tile inside a List View. The child is a container (with Image Carousel Slider ) and footer is a container (with a ListTile as its child). I am getting the following error with a blank screen

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 570 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was:
GridTile GridTile:file:///D:/e_shoppie/lib/pages/item_details.dart:54:11

My Code is-

```
body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          GridTile(
            footer: Container(
              color: Colors.black12,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(
                  widget.productName ?? 'Product Name',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white10,
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: carousel_image_list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                  final imageAdd = carousel_image_list[index];
                  return buildImage(imageAdd, index);
                },
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    setState(() {
                      activeIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  initialPage: 0,
                  height: 200,
                  autoPlay: true,
                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                  viewportFraction: 0.8,
                  pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: true,
                  pauseAutoPlayOnManualNavigate: true,
                  autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                  autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide height on `GridTile` to solve this issue.

```dart
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
children: [
SizedBox(
  height: 200, // based on your need
  child: GridTile(
    footer: Container(
```

Better using `LayoutBuilder`

```dart
return Scaffold(
body: LayoutBuilder(
builder: (context, constraints) => ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: constraints.maxHeight * .6, //getting 60% height of body
      child: GridTile(
        footer: Container(
```

Comment: I used the Sized Box and it solved the problem.

Comment: Can you explain in short what advantage will the Layout Builder have?

Comment: ` LayoutBuilder` gets the parent size, means here scaffold body, using this provide dynamic/responsive look, you can find more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)